# Can't open simulator Android virtual device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-virtual-device

hi i want to open android simulator but it shows like this

Android emulator version 31.3.9.0 (build_id 8700579) (CL:N/A) emulator: INFO: Found systemPath \AndroidStudioSettings\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ emulator: INFO: Found systemPath AndroidStudioSettings\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag

currently i am using intel macbook

i have tried

cmd

```
flutter config --android-sdk pathToYourSDK
```